# ImageMagick - command working on ubuntu but not centos

Tags: centos, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Any idea why the following would work fine on ubuntu:

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 14 label:123 test.jpg
```

but get this response on centos (7)

```
convert: not authorized `123' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/454.
convert: no images defined `test.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3046.
```

I have tried a few different versions on each.

Does it have anything to do with all of this.. which is missing in the centos one?

```
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

and if so, how can I install what is missing?

---

here is my centos version info: (from `yum install ImageMagick`)

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-14 Q16 x86_64 2018-11-17 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): zlib
```

Comment: Have you tried enclosing label:123 in ' ' or " " It looks like to me label:123 is being split into label: and 123

Comment: hi thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried but I get the same result.

Comment: What are your versions of ImageMagick and the dates of those versions. `convert -version`. Try specifying a font. Some systems do not have a default font set up. Do you have the freetype delegate installed? If so, what are the versions. If your Centos does not show the Features and Delegates, that is likely the issue. It was not set up properly. Unless it is a very old version of ImageMagick when those were not reported. See https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php or https://legacy.imagemagick.org/script/download.php to install Centos with IM 7 or IM 6 from binary to include delegates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit /etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml and comment out the "LABEL" line:

```
<!--  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="LABEL" /> -->
```

Don't ask me why this is disabled in CentOS. IM has some known vulnerabilities, and RHEL/CentOS are a bit on the paranoid side.

Comment: Seems to work! Delegates were a red herring I guess.